# Python: Vectorize Calculation Implemented using Iterative Approach

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization

I'm trying to implement some calculation, but I can't figure how to vectorize my code and not using loops.

Let me explain: I have a matrix `M[N,C]` of either `0` or `1`. Another matrix `Y[N,1]` containing values of `[0,C-1]` (My classes). Another matrix `ds[N,M]` which is my dataset.

My output matrix is of size `grad[M,C]` and should be calculated as follow: I'll explain for `grad[:,0]`, same logic for any other column.

For each row(sample) in `ds`, if `Y[that sample] != 0` (The current column of output matrix) and `M[that sample, 0] > 0` , then `grad[:,0] += ds[that sample]`

If `Y[that sample] == 0`, then `grad[:,0] -= (ds[that sample] * <Num of non zeros in M[that sample,:]>`)

Here is my iterative approach:

```
    for i in range(M.size(dim=1)):
        for j in range(ds.size(dim=0)):
            if y[j] == i:
                grad[:,i] = grad[:,i] - (ds[j,:].T * sum(M[j,:]))
            else:
                if M[j,i] > 0:
                    grad[:,i] = grad[:,i] + ds[j,:].T
```

Comment: what is `M` in `grad[M,C]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with three dimensions `n`, `m`, and `c` (in lowercase to avoid ambiguity), it can be useful to change the shape of all your tensors to `(n, m, c)`, by replicating their values over the missing dimension (e.g. `M(m, c)` becomes `M(n, m, c)`).

However, you can skip the explicit replication and use broadcasting, so it is sufficient to unsqueeze the missing dimension (e.g. `M(m, c)` becomes `M(1, m, c)`.

Given these considerations, the vectorization of your code becomes as follows

```
cond = y.unsqueeze(2) == torch.arange(M.size(dim=1)).unsqueeze(0)
pos = ds.unsqueeze(2) * M.unsqueeze(1) * cond
neg = ds.unsqueeze(2) * M.unsqueeze(1).sum(dim=0, keepdim=True) * ~cond
grad += (pos - neg).sum(dim=0)
```

Here is a small test to check the validity of the solution

```
import torch

n, m, c = 11, 5, 7

y = torch.randint(c, size=(n, 1))
ds = torch.rand(n, m)
M = torch.randint(2, size=(n, c))
grad = torch.rand(m, c)


def slow_grad(y, ds, M, grad):
    for i in range(M.size(dim=1)):
        for j in range(ds.size(dim=0)):
            if y[j] == i:
                grad[:,i] = grad[:,i] - (ds[j,:].T * sum(M[j,:]))
            else:
                if M[j,i] > 0:
                    grad[:,i] = grad[:,i] + ds[j,:].T
    return grad


def fast_grad(y, ds, M, grad):
    cond = y.unsqueeze(2) == torch.arange(M.size(dim=1)).unsqueeze(0)
    pos = ds.unsqueeze(2) * M.unsqueeze(1) * cond
    neg = ds.unsqueeze(2) * M.unsqueeze(1).sum(dim=0, keepdim=True) * ~cond
    grad += (pos - neg).sum(dim=0)
    return grad
  
# Assert equality of all elements function outputs, throws an exception if false
assert torch.all(slow_grad(y, ds, M, grad) == fast_grad(y, ds, M, grad))
```

Feel free to test on other cases as well!